# Makeing the <li> scroll sideways with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long list of li and i am only showing 4 of them and the others are hidden.
So what i want is to make two buttons so they can scroll trough the all of the li with jquery.

Here is a skeleton application on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qonbLjny/4/) and i want to have something like [this](http://www.auchan.it/volantino/volantino.php?id=3580&id_pdv=38).
Here is the code that i have.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //When user clicks back button the slider moves to the left
    $('#back').click(function(){
        $('.listImages').animate({left: "-=10px"}, 'fast');
    });
    //When user click forward button the slider moves to the right
    $('#forward').click(function(){
       $('.listImages').animate({left: "+=10px"}, 'fast')
    });


    //When the user clicks on a tumbnail
    $('.sp').click(function(){
        //Removes the previus active class
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        //Add the active class to the click image
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var $largeImage = $('.active').clone();
        $('.mainImage').html($largeImage)
    });
});
```

How is not animating the li and moveing them to the direction i want too? Intead of '.listImages' i have tried '.tumbs' but still didnt work.The other Jquery is working aswell.

Comment: Why don't you just use a pre-built carousel plug-in to do this?

Comment: I dont know anything about it. Can you please give me a link or something.

Comment: Here, check this one: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel  or google 'jquery carousel plugins'

Comment: its not like what i want have to clicked on my second link in the question?i want one something similar to the bottom one.

Comment: I would use CSS to style something already pre-built instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Like what please? because it has t function and work simimlar to the second link that i gave you.

Comment: You can use that carousel plug-in I showed you, and restyle the `.carousel-indicators` class to display your swatches as images.  It's really not that hard to do if you know CSS

Comment: Yea, nobody really builds these things anymore, they usually use something pre-built since it has everything pre-made. Your issue is a styling one, that can be done in CSS.  That's why nobody answered your question, because they know it's more complicated than it looks to build one, rather than using something already out there.

Comment: Ye im not doing it because i want too , its because i have to make something similar to it. Its looks bump n not professional but anyways, thank you for the feed back!

Comment: Here, i think this is more what you're looking for: http://www.sitepoint.com/8-jquery-book-plugins/

Comment: Or here: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/3d-slider-carousel/

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response wasnt at  home. Yes i have found those plugins thank you very much :)